# Функция работает не всегда верно

Tags: javascript

Появилась нужна написать функцию, которая будет возвращать случайное значение от 0 до 55. Я написал вот это:

```
var a;
function random () {
     a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
     if (a >= 55){
         enemyNum();
     }
     else{
         return a;
     }
 }

console.log(random());
```

но она через раз возвращает "undefined", видимо когда результат больше 55. Подскажите как этого избежать?

Answer (score 2):

> которая будет возвращать случайное значение от 0 до 55

Если надо, чтобы 0 и 55 входили в возможные значения:

```js
function random() {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 56);
  return a;
}

console.log(random());
```